# Is it possible to install a distro using a DVD image and a pendrive?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fat32, usb-flash-drive

I have a 8 GB flash drive and a 4.3 GB DVD iso (openSUSE-11.3)
Is it possible to use the flash drive to install the linux?
Pendrive linux universal USB installer formats it to Fat32 which limits the filesystem to 4 GB.

Comment: Consider downloading openSUSE 11.4; see this [openSUSE Wiki portal page](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:11.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) is a tool that will extract the ISO onto a thumbdrive so that you can boot from it. It should work like a DVD would, allowing you to install from the thumbdrive.

Comment: How does this circumvent the Fat32 4GB limitation?

Comment: The utility writes the contents of the ISO image directly to the flash drive as a partition.  The ISO image itself is not written to another filesystem.